# How should I bind a Combobox's ItemsSource to Content and Items

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, expression-blend

## Problem

I have a `UserControl` which contains a `ToggleButton` and a `ComboBox`. The control will allow the user to choose a sort type (via `ComboBox`) and a Direction (via `ToggleButton`). I want to be able to expose some properties of the `ComboBox` and more, so how do I bind the ItemsSource of the `ComboBox` to an `Items` Property of the `UserControl`, which I will implement myself, but also the built-in `Content` property---similar to how a `ComboBox` can do both.

## UserControl

I have a user control which set-up is similar as the below code, or [look here](http://tinypic.com/r/2dt0zfb/5).

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example.DirComboBox">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbItems" />
        <ToggleButton x:Name="tbSortDir"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

## Control Usage

I would like to be able to use it in two ways:

### 1:

Adding Child Elements.

```
<local:DirComboBox>
    <ComboboxItem Content="Item 1"/>
</local:DirComboBox>
```

### 2:

Binding `Items` Property.

```
<local:DirComboBox Items="{Binding SortList}"/>
```

## Alternatives

I would be willing to use alternatives, such as setting the root as `ComboBox` instead of `UserControl` but I need to expose the follow (but not sure how):

1. Have a `ToggleButton` on the side,
2. `SortDirection` property as a bool
3. `RoutedEvent` for `Ascending` and `Descending`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of basing my control on `UserControl` I changed to using a CustomControl as per [the Tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Define Dependancy Properties for `SortDirection`, `Items` in your `usercontrol`. Once you have these properties in your control you can directly set them from outside like:

```
<local:DirComboBox Items="{Binding SortList}" SortDirection="{Binding Sort}"/>
```

then inside your control bind these properties to respective controls like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example.DirComboBox">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"}/>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="tbSortDir" IsPressed="{Binding SortDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

keep the binding mode as twoway.

Comment: The problem I have is that when adding a child element to the control in `MainWindow`, it will remove the grid and the only element in `UserControl` is now that item.

Comment: sorry i did not get it. how are you adding the usercontorl in window?